# Spring: PESSIMISTIC_READ/WRITE not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I have two servers connected to the same database. Both have scheduled jobs I don't really care which one runs the scheduled jobs as long as only one does. So the idea was to keep a key-value pair in DB and whichever reads the value as 0 first gets to run the scheduled job.

Ideally this would work as so:

1. App A and App B run the scheduled job at the same time.
2. App A access the DB first, locks the table for reading & writing.
3. App A sets value to 1 and releases the lock.
4. App A starts working on the scheduled job.
5. App B reads the value 1 from it's DB request and does not run the scheduled job.

I have a config table where I keep status on my locks.

```
config:  
  name: VARCHAR(55)
  value: VARCHAR(55)
```

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ConfigRepository extends CrudRepository<Config, Long> {
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
    Config findOneByName(String name);

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    <S extends Config> S save(S entity);
}
```

The service:

```
@Service
public class ConfigService {
    @Transactional
    public void unlock(ConfigEnum lockable) {
        Config lock = configRepository.findOneByName(lockable.getSetting());
        lock.setValue("0");
        configRepository.save(lock);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void lock(ConfigEnum lockable) {
        Config lock = configRepository.findOneByName(lockable.getSetting());
        lock.setValue("1");
        configRepository.save(lock);
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean isLocked(ConfigEnum lockable) {
        Config lock = configRepository.findOneByName(lockable.getSetting());
        return lock.getValue().equals("1");
    }
}
```

The Scheduler:

```
@Component
public class JobScheduler {
    @Async
    @Scheduled("0 0 1 * * *")
    @Transactional
    public void run() {
       if (!configService.isLocked(ConfigEnum.CNF_JOB.getJobName())) {
           configService.lock(ConfigEnum.CNF_JOB.getJobName());
           jobService.run();
           configService.unlock(ConfigEnum.CNF_JOB.getJobName());
       }
    }
}
```

However I have noticed that the scheduled jobs still run at the same time on both apps. At times one will throw a deadlock but it appears that Spring retries the transaction if it hits a deadlock. At which time it appears that the one app has finished so this one begins the same job again (not sure).

The tasks are not that short that a lock could be established, table updated, task run and lock released. I would like to keep this really simple without involving additional libraries like Quartz or ShedLock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your transactions are too short. You don't start a transaction in the run method, but each ConfigService method is transactional. Most likely each method gets a new transaction and commits when done. A commit will release the lock, so there is a race condition between isLocked and lock.

Combine isLocked and lock:

```
@Transactional
public boolean tryLock(ConfigEnum lockable) {
    Config lock = configRepository.findOneByName(lockable.getSetting());
    if("1".equals(lock.getValue()) {
        return false;
    }
    lock.setValue("1");
    configRepository.save(lock);
    return true;
}
```

This checks and writes in the same transaction and should work.

As a side note it is a dangerous method. What happens if the node that has the lock dies? There are many possible solutions. One is to lock a specific record and keep that lock throughout the job. The other node cannot proceed and if the first one dies the lock will be released. Another is to use a timestamp instead of 1 and require the timestamp to be updated on a regular basis by the owner. Or you could introduce something like Zookeeper.

Comment: Ups. I forgot I do have `@Transactional` and `@Async` annotations on the `run()` method as well. I will try your suggestion and add a timestamp as well to control cases with failed nodes.

Comment: Note that if you make the entire run method transactional you may get issues with timeouts if the jobs are long. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm. I removed `@Transactional` from `run()` as well.